# Can multiple processes creating the same intermediate directories get into a race condition in UNIX?

Tags: python, linux, unix, concurrency

Given this piece of Python code

```py
from pathlib import Path


def create_dir(last_component: str):
    path = Path("l1/l2") / last_component
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

If there two concurrent processes, not threads, that at the same time, call `create_dir` defined above as

```py
# The call by process 1
create_dir('sub1')
```

and

```py
# The call by process 2
create_dir('sub2')
```

Assuming that both processes have the same current working directory which is empty, not having a subdirectory named `l1`. Is it possibly that these two processes enter into a race condition that corrupt the file system or produces an unexpected result? (I only need the answer for UNIX systems.)

**Background information of the above question:**
I am running a remote [Celery worker](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html) that have many parallel processes. These processes are responsible for putting contents into directories in the file system. Each unit of content is put into a directory of 3 levels in depth.

For example,

For content1, it would be put into `l1_dir_name1/l2_dir_name1/content1_dir`. For content2, it would be put into `l1_dir_name2/l2_dir_name2/content2_dir`. It is possibly that `l1_dir_name1` is the same as `l1_dir_name2` and `l2_dir_name1` is the same as `l2_dir_name2`.

Comment: If directory names are unique, there can be no race.

Comment: User-mode processes can't corrupt the filesystem unless there's a bug in the kernel. Depending on how the `path.mkdir()` function is implemented there can be race conditions in the library, potentially causing a Python error, but it shouldn't break the filesystem.

Comment: @BurakSerdar The final components of the directory names are unique. However, the intermediate/parent directories can be the same, as in `l1/l2/sub1` and `l1/l2/sub2`.

Comment: @Barmar I am running the Celery worker with the the root user in a container. However, the location the worker is writing the content to bind mount volume from the host. Can the filesystem be corrupted in this case?

Comment: I don't think containers bypass the kernel API to the filesystem, it serializes everything.

Comment: The only way to corrupt the filesystem is to write directly to the device file instead of going through the filesystem.